# Can 2FA / MFA be secure & functional in a purely offline state (PWA)?

Tags: authentication, passwords, multi-factor, one-time-password

I'm building a Progressive Web App intended to be used primarily in an offline state. The user can "login" while disconnected, which verifies the password against a locally-stored hash and some other stuff.

The idea has been proposed to add 2FA to the offline login to make it "more secure". However, my (limited) understanding of MFA tells me that I'd have to store the 2FA secret key locally, and this code could be retrieved and probably be used to reverse engineer the auth code, making the whole thing moot.

(For the sake of argument, let's pretend this isn't JavaScript and a malicious actor can't just "skip" past my login process to access the app offline without logging in.)

Am I correct in my assumption that this is a dead-end? Or is there a way to do 2FA purely offline in a secure manner? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Authentication against a local application is a lost battle anyways.

Comment: Yeah. For the sake of argument, let's say it's not. I want to focus on the nuts and bolts of MFA.

Comment: you could encrypt the app's code, then decode it with a password supplied by the user. that way the app can't run w/o the password, and you don't have to store the password to verify it. you don't have to do all the code, just enough to secure it and prevent debugging-based by-passes.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication against a local JS application does not work. I wrote [a detailed answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/212209/163495) on this topic before. The crux of the argument is that an attacker is in complete control over the mechanism that performs the authentication, and is therefore able to always authenticate themselves successfully.

> What about Multi-Factor Authentication?

It will not fare any better. Imagine a simple scenario, in which your application would send an SMS token to your user, once they entered the correct password. An attacker can simply read out which value is expected, and enter that value.

> But what if an attacker would not be able to skip past my login?

That's the problem. In any even remotely realistic scenario, you don't get to tell the attacker how they can attack your application.

**An offline JavaScript application can't securely authenticate a user, because the attacker is completely in charge of the authentication process**.

Comment: The password (and potentially MFA code), after being validated, after used to generate a key that can decrypt necessary information. If the user bypassed authentication schemes, they would still not have a decryption key and thus can't do anything of value. That is why I would like to focus on the MFA piece exclusively, per the statement in my original question.

Comment: That would be a huge design flaw, as it would require you sending all confidential information to every user. Furthermore, 2FA in all useful cases, is something dynamic - i.e. a one-time token sent via a second channel. You can't use dynamic components to decrypt something.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sending all confidential information to every user. Many apps receive confidential information. That's why TLS exists.

Comment: One of the scarier parts is, the credentials -- whether it be a key-stretched password, a public key, or whatever -- is on the client machine. Security conscious web developers assume the table with those credentials will targeted by attackers, but it's one thing to assume it will one day be leaked; it's another to hand it out to anyone who asks.

Comment: @Ghedipunk The password credentials are strongly hashed. As for MFA, well... that's what I'm trying to determine from my question.

Comment: @CandidGoose "The password credentials are strongly hashed" ... and they're in the hands of potentially malicious actors. -- My point is, even though developers are urged not to assume their database will always be secure, _securing that data is still always beneficial_.  That includes not sending the key-stretched password to any client under any circumstances.

Comment: Key stretching a password might make it more difficult to guess a password, but it takes seconds to break "p@ssw0rd" even when you're using Argon2id.

Comment: The password is not "sent" to the client. It's input by the client in the same way that you input your credentials on any other web site. It's then hashed. Sorry, but I don't have any fears of malicious actors having the hash. That's what hashes are for. It cannot be used for a Pass the Hash attack, etc due to other precautions taken. 

More apps do this than you may realize - hell, even the link @MechMK1 posted has half a dozen people saying they're doing the same thing I'm doing.

Still waiting for some MFA-specific technical knowledge to arrive.

Comment: @CandidGoose The "MFA-specific knowledge" you are "waiting to arrive" (which is quite a rude tone to people who help you for literally nothing in exchange), has already arrived in [this comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220529/can-2fa-mfa-be-secure-functional-in-a-purely-offline-state-pwa/220533?noredirect=1#comment448364_220533). Proper 2FA requires dynamic components. If your pseudo-authentication scheme is based on the decryption of data, it just does not work.

Comment: "Help" is subjective. In my initial question, I made the statement to hypothetically assume JavaScript code could not be modified or circumvented, *for the sake of discussion*. You then made a comment saying JS can be circumvented - I agreed and asked to ignore that point for my hypothetical. You then posted an entire answer that continued ignoring the hypothetical and declaring the obvious. Is that considered "help" to you? 

This is part of what makes many people I know hesitant to ask a question on this site. People assaulting their use case, making assumptions, or ignoring the question.